# Tab Content loading in main active tab error-PHP with Bootstrap 4

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I created navigation tabs that load content when you click the tab. But in the active tab, the content of all the tabs is loading. I have included a PHP file to load the content but when I remove the PHP file and put normal content it's working properly.

```
     <div class="nav-tabs-horizontal" data-plugin="tabs">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-line" role="tablist">
                  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#settingsTab"
                      aria-controls="settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#locationsTab"
                      aria-controls="locations" role="tab">Buisness </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#taxTab"
                      aria-controls="tax" role="tab">Tax</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#productsettingsTab"
                      aria-controls="product" role="tab">
                      Product </a>  
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#invoiceTab"
                    aria-controls="invoiceTab" role="tab">Invoice Settings
                    </a>
                    </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#emailTab"
                    aria-controls="emailTab" role="tab">Email Settings
                    </a>
                    </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#audit"
                  aria-controls="audit" role="tab">Audit</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content ">
                  <div class="tab-pane active" id="settingsTab" >
                  <?php include 'settings.php'; ?>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="locationsTab" >
                  <?php include 'locations.php'; ?>
                   </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane " id="taxTab" >
                  <?php include 'tax.php'; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane " id="productsettingsTab" >
                  <?php include 'product.php'; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane " id="invoiceTab" >
                  <?php include 'invoice.php'; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane " id="emailTab" >
                  <?php include 'email.php'; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane " id="audit" >
                  <?php include 'auditlogs.php'; ?>
                  </div>
                 
                
                </div>
              </div>
```

[image: Below is the screen I am getting]

Comment: Need more Clarity to the Questions Check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you post the content for the included page? If there is a markup issue then it may fail to comply right?

Comment: @Amalnandan hi thankyou for your concern.I have added a image.

Comment: @ManishSoni  I have tried different pages by including them in php tag.Still the same is issue coming.

Comment: As per the image your issue is different. Some of the file (either bootstrap or jquery) is not loading in correct order. Open the console, and check the error if you see any.

Comment: @ManishSoni Thankyou.I solved the issue.Some files were not loading.

Comment: @dimuthu_fernando, ok its glad that you got it resolved. Can you please accept my answer below?

Comment: @ManishSoni Sorry,I need more reputation to accept the answer.

Comment: Sure, No Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the screen, it appears that few files (either bootstrap or jquery)  are not loading. Please correct them.